# The predict method shows standardized probability?

Tags: python-2.7, probability, scikit-learn, prediction, adaboost

I'm using the AdaBoostClassifier in Scikit-learn and always get an average probability of 0.5 regardless of how unbalanced the training sets are. The class predictions (predict_) seems to give correct estimates, but these aren't reflected in the predict_probas method which always average to 0.5.

If my "real" probability is 0.02, how do I transform the standardized probability to reflect that proportion?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you get probabilities per sample that are 1/n_classes on average? That's necessarily the case; the probabilities reported by `predict_proba` are the conditional class probability distribution P(y|X) over all values for y. To produce different probabilities, perform any necessary computations according to your probability model.

Comment: Yes. In the NaiveBayes algorithm, there is apparently a class_prior parameter (for instance [0.2, 0.8]). This seems to be what I'm looking for, even though the AdaBoostClassifier doesn't allow it. Would I be right to just multiply the predict_proba response with the inverse of the class (1/0.2 or 1/0.8) to get a number corresponding to the class prior?

Comment: @OlaGustafsson You can multiply with whatever you want. If you renormalize afterwards, then what you have is a classifier with an additional prior, i.e. a kind of mixture model.